# Running asynchronous query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, asynchronous, odbc

I'm trying to run some heavy queries asynchronously, but can't figure out how to do it for an .mdb file.

This is what I have so far:

```
 Dim wrksp As Workspace, qdf As QueryDef, rst As Recordset
Dim cnn As Connection, strConnect As String

Set wrksp = CreateWorkspace("ODBCDirect", "Admin", "", dbUseODBC)


strConnect = "ODBC;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Database=F:\Databank\webshop_ingrid.mde;Uid=;Pwd=;"

Set cnn = wrksp.OpenConnection("", dbDriverNoPrompt, False, _
                               strConnect)

Dim rs As Recordset



  Dim strQuery As String
  strQuery = "UPDATE ((((((tblSkuActueel LEFT JOIN qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery.sku) LEFT JOIN " & _
  "qrySkuCapNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuCapNieuwste.sku) LEFT JOIN qrySkuListNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuListNieuwste.sku) LEFT JOIN " & _
  "qrySkuPPDNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuPPDNieuwste.sku) INNER JOIN qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.sku) " & _
  "LEFT JOIN qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteDS ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteDS.sku) LEFT JOIN qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteNB ON tblSkuActueel.sku = " & _
  "qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteNB.sku SET tblSkuActueel.stock = qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery.aantal, tblSkuActueel.apex = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.apex, " & _
  "tblSkuActueel.cap = qrySkuCapNieuwste.cap, tblSkuActueel.listprice = qrySkuListNieuwste.listprice, tblSkuActueel.ppd = qrySkuPPDNieuwste.ppd, " & _
  "tblSkuActueel.procent = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.procent, tblSkuActueel.apin = Round(qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.apex*qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.procent,2), " & _
  "tblSkuActueel.BtwId = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.btwid, tblSkuActueel.specialpricenb = [qryskuspecialnieuwstenb].[specialprice], " & _
  "tblSkuActueel.specialpriceds = [qryskuspecialnieuwsteds].[specialprice]"

  Set rs = Object.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges + dbRunAsync)
```

That won't even open a connection as the connection string seems to be wrong.

Comment: The discussion in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898953/multi-thread-in-ms-access-async-processing) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first 5 (non-blank) lines are doing nothing in your example.  Those lines are attempting to open a connection, but your later code that is dealing with the update query is not using that connection.

You should be aware that the Round() function that you are using may not return what you expect.  The Round() function in VBA uses "Bankers Rounding" or "round half to even" logic.  Both Round(15.665,2) and Round(15.675,2) will return 15.67.

Your final line is attempting to open a recordset from your update statement.  The update statement does not return records, so there is no recordset to return.  If it were to return a recordset, you would want to use something like "CurrentDB.OpenRecordset" rather than "Object.OpenRecordset".

Regarding asynchronous running of this query, you may not be able to get what you want.  MS Access is going to process the query on the local computer.  I do not know of a way to run a query asynchronously if it is using a JET (MS Access) database.  I suspect that even if there is a command to run the query asynchronously through your VBA code, it would still be running in the context of your application and bog it down.

If you are trying to let your application be responsive while the query is running I would suggest moving the update to a separate process, for example a VBScript file.

Save the following code in a file with a name like UpdateActueel.vbs

```
strQuery = "UPDATE ((((((tblSkuActueel LEFT JOIN qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery.sku) LEFT JOIN " & _
"qrySkuCapNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuCapNieuwste.sku) LEFT JOIN qrySkuListNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuListNieuwste.sku) LEFT JOIN " & _
"qrySkuPPDNieuwste ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuPPDNieuwste.sku) INNER JOIN qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.sku) " & _
"LEFT JOIN qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteDS ON tblSkuActueel.sku = qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteDS.sku) LEFT JOIN qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteNB ON tblSkuActueel.sku = " & _
"qrySkuSpecialNieuwsteNB.sku SET tblSkuActueel.stock = qryStockSkuMetLaatsteDatumSubQuery.aantal, tblSkuActueel.apex = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.apex, " & _
"tblSkuActueel.cap = qrySkuCapNieuwste.cap, tblSkuActueel.listprice = qrySkuListNieuwste.listprice, tblSkuActueel.ppd = qrySkuPPDNieuwste.ppd, " & _
"tblSkuActueel.procent = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.procent, tblSkuActueel.apin = Round(qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.apex*qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.procent,2), " & _
"tblSkuActueel.BtwId = qrySkuApexNieuwsteMetBtw.btwid, tblSkuActueel.specialpricenb = [qryskuspecialnieuwstenb].[specialprice], " & _
"tblSkuActueel.specialpriceds = [qryskuspecialnieuwsteds].[specialprice]"

Set DB = GetObject("F:\Databank\webshop_ingrid.mde")
DB.Execute strQuery
```

And in your VBA code, use the following line to run the script.

```
Shell "wscript ""C:\<Path to file>\UpdateActueel.vbs"""
```

Comment: ADO recordsets can be DML queries, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I can speak about executing this things against a JET data source however I have used this against SQL server so it should work. The trick is to use ADO and fire the execute statement with the option adAsyncExecute. I don’t have the exact code to hand but here is a rough version off the top of my head

> Dim DbCon as ADODB.Connection
>
> Dim dbCmd as ADODB.Command
>
> DbCon.ConnectionString=”Your
> connection string”
>
> With dbCmd
> .commandtype= adCmdText
>
> .commandtext=”Your long SQL update statement”
> .ActiveConnection=dbcon
>
> .Execute , , adAsyncExecute
>
> End With

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it works for MDB databases, because it complains about OLE DB objects 'which are not supported by the current provider'

Comment: Worth a shot, can you tell me which line of the code it errors out on?