# Is there a keyboard shortcut to stop Access from refreshing linked tables/queries once it has started?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have quite a few Access Databases with large queries, which link via ODBC to larger SQL databases, etc. Sometimes I run a query, then realize I want to make a change to that query, only to be stuck waiting several minutes for that query to finally finish running, before I can get back into the Access SQL view and modify my query criteria.

I know that most compilers have button combo which you can press to stop compiling a program once it has started. For Netbeans it is Ctrl-C.

I also realize that a RDBMS is not a compiler. But I figured it couldn't hurt to ask if there was any sort of similar command in MS Access, or, if one could be added via the use of VBA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS Access cancel execution of pass-thru query keyboard shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896845/ms-access-cancel-execution-of-pass-thru-query-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrl+Break is the shortcut in Access to halt a query.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but which button is the break command typically assigned too?

Comment: Typically "Pause / Break" somewhere up by print screen and scroll lock.

Comment: Dear God there is a Break button on the keyboard. Well who would have thunk it... Can't believe I forgot about that.